# Return a modified tree with brackets added to each node

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, tree, tuples

I have a function that goes through each node in a tree and I'm trying to create a modified tree with brackets added to each node.

Since tuples are immutable I know I can't select the node by index and and add the brackets that way and so I have been trying to think how I can reconstruct the tree back to its original state with brackets around each node.

```
def add_brackets(node):
  parent, children = node
  for child in children:
    add_brackets(child)
```

for,

```
("hello", (("a", ()), ("b", (("cde", ()), ("fg", ())))))
```

I'm wanting to return,

```
('[hello]', (('[a]', ()), ('[b]', (('[cde]', ()), ('[fg]', ())))))
```

how can I do this?

Comment: How you defined your tree class?

Comment: @XinlinFeng, I didn't think I needed a class for the tree since its represented as tuples..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yup, tuples are immutable, you need to construct new ones and return them instead.

try this:

```py
def add_brackets(node):
    parent, children = node
    new_parent = "[{}]".format(parent)
    new_children = tuple(add_brackets(child) for child in children)
    return (new_parent, new_children)


root = ("hello", (("a", ()), ("b", (("cde", ()), ("fg", ())))))
root = add_brackets(root)
print(root)
```

Output:

```
('[hello]', (('[a]', ()), ('[b]', (('[cde]', ()), ('[fg]', ())))))
```

Comment: I was wondering how new_children could be modified so that a leaf could have a new child added to it based on some condition? @Adam.Er8